# Prove ${\bf u}.{\bf Tv} = ({\bf u} \otimes {\bf v}) : {\bf T}$

Tags: tensors

Example 8 (on Page 6) of these [lecture notes](https://nptel.ac.in/content/storage2/courses/112103167/module2/lec14.pdf#page=6) appear to suggest that for any vectors $\bf u$ and $\bf v$ and tensor $\bf T$

$
{\bf u}.{\bf Tv} = ({\bf u} \otimes {\bf v}) : {\bf T}
$

I'd appreciate help proving this.

Comment: What does the colon notation mean?

Comment: @CameronWilliams It's a notation for the [Frobenius inner product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_inner_product)

Comment: @CameronWilliams In "dyadics", I guess they would call it the [double dot product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyadics#Double-dot_product)

Comment: @Omnomnomnom that was my suspicion but I wasn't sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To reframe this in terms of matrix multiplication, note that for column-vectors $x,y$ and matrices $A,B$ of the same shape, we have

- $x \cdot y = x^\top y$,
- $u \otimes v = uv^\top $,
- $A : B = \operatorname{Tr}(A^\top B)$.

With that, we can prove this result as a consequence of the [cyclic property of trace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_(linear_algebra)#Cyclic_property). Or, if you prefer, we could use the slightly simpler result $\operatorname{Tr}(xy^\top) = x^\top y$ for column-vectors $x,y$.  In any case, we have
$$
(u \otimes v): T = \operatorname{Tr}((uv^\top)^\top T) = 
\operatorname{Tr}(v u^\top T) =
\operatorname{Tr}(u^\top Tv) = u^\top (Tv) = u \cdot Tv
$$
as desired.

---

If we want to stick to dyadic notation, we might state the following: $T$ can necessarily be written as a sum $T = x_i \otimes y_i$ for some vectors $x_i,y_i$. It follows that 
$$
(u \otimes v) : T = (u \otimes v):(x_i \otimes y_i) = (u \cdot x_i)(v \cdot y_i),\\
u \cdot Tv = u \cdot (x_i \otimes y_i)v = (u \cdot x_i)(v \cdot y_i).
$$
It follows that the two expressions are indeed equal.